# Por que efeito lightbox do Simple Image Gallery não funciona no SP PageBuilder?

Tags: jquery, joomla

Estou criando um site em joomla e agora me deparei com um bug que não consigo resolver. Uso o construtor de páginas SP pagebuider e template Helix3 e adicionei no site a extensão Simple Image Gallery, em um artigo. As miniaturas aparecem perfeitamente, mas ao clicar nelas ao invés da imagem aparecer em lightbox, ela abre uma nova janela com a imagem original estática.

Na console do chrome aparece o seguinte erro:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (main.js:96)
at i (jquery.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)
at HTMLDocument.K (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Este arquivo mais.js é do template Helix3 que uso para todo o site.

Nós fóruns que li onde falam do problema, tentei as alternativas citadas e nada deu certo.

Já instalei as extensões Easy jquery e  jqueryintegrator sem sucesso.

Ja adicionei o código noconflict e erro também continuou.

Alguém sabe o que posso fazer para resolver este problema?

Obrigado por qualquer resposta

Comment: Você verificou a ordem dos plugins? Tente inverter o plugin do SP Page Builder com Simple Image Gallery. Já tive alguns problemas parecidos e resolvi apenas trocando a ordem em que o Joomla carrega um plugin.

Comment: obrigado @Wesley pela resposta, como eu faria isto? nunca inverti a ordem dos plugins no joomla, nao sei como fazer

Comment: https://www.regularlabs.com/blog/242-plugin-order-is-important acesse a página de plugins no seu painel administrativo, clique sobre o plugin que deseja alterar a ordem, e ao lado direito verá "Ordem". No link que enviei você pode ver um vídeo de como fazer.